# as.numeric of "<2.0e-10"?

Tags: r

I have a vector of p.values and I'd change these extremes to systemic mininum values like `<2.0e-10`. I'm wondering whether there is a way to make them as if they were numeric so that I can make plot and comparison etc. For example:

```
x0<-c(2.0e-18, 1.0e-40, 0.001, 0.05, 5.0e-5)
```

Then I replace the first two to "<2.0e-16":

```
x1<-ifelse(x0<2.0e-16, "<2.0e-16", x0)
x1
[1] "<2.0e-16" "<2.0e-16" "0.001"    "0.05"     "5e-05"
```

What I would like is to make x1 equivalent to its numeric one x2 such as:

```
x2<-c(2.0e-16, 2.0e-16, 0.001, 0.05, 5.0e-5)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What type of plot are you making? I't probably better to truncate the values and worry about adjusting your plot axis labels rather than trying to come up with data that is both numeric and character.

Comment: You can do what you want with `x2 <- as.numeric(gsub("<", "", x1))` but that looks like an horrible way of dealing with your data.

Comment: `format.pval(x0, eps = 2e-16)` and `as.numeric(gsub('<', '', format.pval(x0, eps = 2e-16)))`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just directly transform `x0<2.0e-16` to `2.0e-16`. The following gives your expected output :

```
x0 <- c(2.0e-18, 1.0e-40, 0.001, 0.05, 5.0e-5)
x1 <- ifelse(x0<2.0e-16, 2.0e-16, x0)

x2 <- c(2.0e-16, 2.0e-16, 0.001, 0.05, 5.0e-5)

identical(x1,x2)
[1] TRUE
```